# Word for "what-if scenarios"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives

What is the English word that best captures "what if" situation? Something along the lines of "What if something goes wrong". It is close to being pessimistic. But *pessimistic* is too negative.

I am basically looking for a word that captures "what-if situations" rather than the expression "what if" itself. "Worst-case" is not a choice for me.

Comment: Scenarios? Possibilities? Hypotheses? Imaginings? Thought experiments? Considerations?

Comment: Is it important that the word you seek has a negative connotation, although less negative than "worst-case" or "pessimistic"?

Comment: @MattЭллен yes negative connotation

Comment: What about "risk management"?

Comment: “In most cases a *contingency plan* is associated with risk management in a project, in the case a risk occurs these actions have to be taken to control/mitigate the risk. / A ***fall back plan*** is an alternative in case a certain approach fails.” — [ProjectManagement.com](https://www.projectmanagement.com/discussion-topic/12584/Contingency-plans-vs-fallback-plans- "Contingency plans vs Fallback plans")

Answer (score 6):

The most obvious word that comes to mind is "*hypotheticals*". It does not refer to exclusively positive or negative scenarios, but to any imagined, "what if" scenarios.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypotheticals):

> **Hypotheticals** are situations, statements or questions about something imaginary rather than something real. Hypotheticals deal with the concept of "what if?"'. Grammatically, the term is a noun formed from an adjective, and the word is pluralized because it refers to the *members* of a *class* of hypothetical things.

Comment: thank you but i believe , its not so commonly used word, so my readers may not easily read my mind if i use this word

Comment: @sashank I believe the term would be pretty widely understood in most contexts, and among most audiences. However, you can use "*hypothetical situation*" or "*hypothetical scenario*" if you want to keep it simple. Also, I think almost everybody would understand you if you simply use "*'what if' scenario*".

Answer (score 2):

Possibilities.  What-if scenarios are the possibilities.

Comment: This is more of a "comment" than an answer. Comments can include opinions and additional information, such as this.

Answer (score 2):

"Contingency preparations" is what I would use.

Comment: Hi, Megan, welcome to EL&U! I like your suggestion for this situation. You could strengthen your answer and get more up-votes if you add an explanation of why this answer fits the OP's question, possibly including a definition cited from a dictionary. Although, with older questions, your answer might not get much attention in any case. You can see more about writing good answers (and questions) in the [Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help). Check it out, and see if any of our newer questions look interesting. Good luck--I look forward to seeing more contributions from you!

Comment: I second @1006a's suggestions.  It would be a really good answer if you fleshed it out and provided more context and references.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I think ***scenario*** is going to be your best word.

It's very flexible for the context you suggest.

- Best-case scenario
- Worst-case scenario
- If Hitler had won the war, the scenario...
- In what scenario could you see that happen?

It lends itself perfectly to "what if" situations.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretical.

Potential.

Supposition.

Comment: Good options. Don't know why someone down-voted.